# How to 'store' email templates in the site?

Tags: 7, emails

On certain events, defined in code, specific mails are sent to certain users in the site (such as on node_save if some value has changed etc).

The content managers need access to those mail templates in order to be able to change literals.

I've thought about having the mail's body inside the node as a field with a 'dummy' default value, but that seems a bit crude. Is there a better way to have my mail templates stored somewhere in the site and access them from code?

Comment: Crude but does the job...

Comment: Agreed, but I'd like something like an 'email section' somewhere with my templates stored in there :) Makes more sense admin-wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"There is a module for that!"

Well of course there is :)

http://drupal.org/project/pet worked wonders for my case. Supports tokens, and provides a hook for aditional tokens, you just need to invoke `pet_send_mail` with the correct arguments and having set up a mail template before hand it will do the work for you. No need to invoke `hook_mail` manually.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on usage patterns of that feature.

For example if you only need one master template and edits are global (e.g apply to all events) then the "correct" storage could be inside the `variable` table.

You can expand on the above design by suffixing those `variable` keys with the node type (or whatever differentiates one template from another). So you could have entries such as:

- mail_template_event
- mail_template_publication
- mail_template_press_release

or in the case of "typed" events:

- mail_template_event_internal
- mail_template_event_external
- mail_template_event_generic

Keeping the mail template on a node field will be easier in terms of programming though. Because if you fetch the template from an "external" source (such as the `variable` table) you'll need to handle presentation within the node edit screen and update of the template in case it was altered.